# removing object from nested array of objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got collection with volunteer information in it, and it lists the volunteers as an array of objects.  I can display all the shifts for each volunteer, but removing one from the array is proving difficult for me:

Sample data:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59180305c19dbaa4ecd9ee59"),
    "where" : "Merchandise tent",
    "description" : "Sell gear at the merchandise tent.",
    "shifts" : [
            {
                    "dateNeeded" : ISODate("2017-06-23T00:00:00Z"),
                    "timeslot" : "8:00 - NOON",
                    "needed" : 2,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("591807546a71c3a57d1a2105"),
                    "volunteers" : [
                            {
                                    "fullname" : "Mary Mack",
                                    "phone" : "1234567890",
                                    "email" : "mary@gmail.com",
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("591ce45bc7e8a8c7b742474c")
                            }
                    ]
            },
```

The data I have available for this is:
_id, where, shifts.timeslot, shifts.dateNeeded, volunteers.email

Can someone help me?  Lets say Mary Mack wants to unVolunteer for the 8 - Noon shift at the merchandise tent.  She may be listed under other shifts as well, but we only want to remove her from this shift.

Comment: @D-reaper The question was incorrectly tagged with angular and javascript. It's actually asking about a MongoDB operation.

Comment: considering that I'm using angularjs as well as mongodb, I didn't know if there was a way I could use angularjs to update the array and then submit the change, or if I had to do it all through mongodb.  I'm sure there are several ways, no?

Comment: To actually update the database? No. You need to issue a command to MongoDB. Array manipulation  in the client does not update the database.

Comment: That much I know, but I thought it might be easier to splice the array in angularjs and then update the record in mongodb cause I wasn't sure of how to do it in mongodb itself.  It seems there are multiple ways, but I did get a great answer below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by specifying something to match the "document" and then the required "shifts" array entry as the query expression for an `.update()`. Then apply the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for the matched array index with [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

```js
db.collection.update(
 { "_id": ObjectId("59180305c19dbaa4ecd9ee59"), "shifts.timeslot": "8:00 - NOON" },
 { "$pull": { "shifts.$.volunteers": { "fullname": "Mary Mack" } } }
)
```

That is okay in this instance since you are only trying to "match" on the "outer" array in the nested structure and the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) has query arguments of it's own to identify the array entry to remove.

You really should be careful using "nested arrays" though. As whilst a [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operation like this works, updates to the "inner" array are not really possible since the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will only match the "first" element that meets the condition. So your example of "Mary Mack" in multiple shifts would only ever match in the first "shifts" array entry found.

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying and was close, but wasn't sure it would work.    I also thought I might be able to splice the array in angularjs and then update it, but it seemed so complicated.

Comment: @user3561890 Whilst you "can" manipulate arrays in the client and save back the details, to do so is not very "safe". You run the risk in real environments that some other process has updated the data and end up overwriting those actions. The other thing you should take away here is noting that nested arrays are not the best design pattern. IMHO I would "flatten" your structure to include the "shift" information on a top level list of "volunteers" rather than embedding the list of volunteers in each shift.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  That is helpful.  I'm trying to convert a lot of my code from the frontend to the backend as far as the processing goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.example.update(
 {},
 { $unset: {"Mary Mack":1}},
 false, true
)
```

Comment: `$unset` removes document properties. The OP is asking to remove an entry from an array

Comment: This is true.  I definitely wanted to remove the entire object from the array, but I sure do appreciate the thought.

Comment: It would be beneficial to include some explanation of why you see this as an answer to the asker's question, rather than just posting a block of code.